# Add to "open recent files"

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

How can I add click event to newly added item of menu? Below is what I've done so far. Obviously my way it very amateurish, so what may be a better way?

```
Collection<string> recent_cases = new Collection<string>();

recent_cases.Insert(0, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName));

if (recent_cases.Count == 6)
{
    recent_cases.RemoveAt(5);
}

for (int i = 0; i < recent_cases.Count; ++i)
{
    MenuItem_OpenRecent.Items.Add(recent_cases[i]);                    
}
```

Comment: your list will always have a single element and never hit the first if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MenuItem normally invokes a Command rather than having you listen to click events.

Given that this is a recently used files list, I assume the command will be "Open File" or something similar, and that this command already exists.

If the user picks a recently used file, you will want to call this same command, but additionally provide the filename as a command parameter.

So:

```
void OnNewFilenameAdded(string filename)
{
    var item = new MenuItem();
    item.Command = _OpenFileCommand;
    item.Header  = filename;
    item.CommandParameter = filename;
    MenuItem_OpenRecent.Items.Insert(0, item);

    if (MenuItem_OpenRecent.Items.Count == 6)
        MenuItem_OpenRecent.Items.RemoveAt(5);
}
```

If you really want to keep a separate collection of filenames, such as if you were going to implement this with MVVM, then take a look at the `Queue<>` class.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick

```
for (int i = 0; i < recent_cases.Count; ++i)
{
    var mi= new MenuItem();
    mi.Header = recent_cases[i];
    mi.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItem_Click);
    MenuItem_OpenRecent.Items.Add(mi);                    
}


....


void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mi= sender as MenuItem;
    //Do stuff with your file
}
```